# sed and "system" in Perl Concatenation

Tags: perl, unix, sed, concatenation

I'm trying to transform a file text in a specific format so I use a lot of "sed"

when I try all my command line on unix it works but when I put the command in my script perl like this :

```
system "sed 's/( )//g' prix$arg1.txt>prixmodifAyc.txt";
system "sed 's/ /|/g' prixmodifAyc.txt>prixmodifAyc3.txt";
system "sed 's/||/|/g' prixmodifAyc3.txt>prixmodifAyc4.txt";
system "sed 's/||/|/g' prixmodifAyc4.txt>prixmodifAyc5.txt";
system "sed 's/||/|/g' prixmodifAyc5.txt>prixmodifAyc6.txt";
system "sed 's/||/|/g' prixmodifAyc6.txt>prixmodifAyc7.txt";
system "sed 's/||/|/g' prixmodifAyc7.txt>prixmodifAyc8.txt";
system "sed 's/|€|/|/g' prixmodifAyc8.txt>prixmodifAyc9.txt";
system "sed 's/|key/ key/g' prixmodifAyc9.txt>prixmodifAyc10.txt";
system "sed 's/%|/|/g' prixmodifAyc10.txt>prixmodifAyc11.txt";
system "sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' prixmodifAyc11.txt>prixmodifAyc12.txt";
```

All lines works but not the last one and I can't find why (I'm not an expert of perl at all and I'm really sorry if my post is not understandable but english is not my main language.)

The error I got is in french :

sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 10: commande `s' inachevée

I think that its a concatenation problem (as the command works in terminal) but I can't find where is the problem hope someone will be able to help

Comment: Because its a Perl script I use "system" to use unix command inside (its just a part of the script)

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: Don't forget that `$` and `\ ` are special characters in double-quoted strings...

Comment: Thanks Ikegami I already tried to put a \ before the $ but I forgot before the \ its finaly appear yo works thanks you very much :)

Comment: egad, why are you calling out to sed from perl? perl can do everything sed can do, and certainly faster without having to invoke a shell and sed several times.

Comment: You could also condense all those `s/||/|/g` replacements into just one regex, something like `s/|\{2,6\}/|/g`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that `$` and `\` are special characters in double-quoted strings. You're actually execucting something like

```
sed ':a;N;0ba;s/
//g' prixmodifAyc11.txt>prixmodifAyc12.txt
```

You could use

```
system "sed ':a;N;\$!ba;s/\\n//g' prixmodifAyc11.txt >prixmodifAyc12.txt";
```

or

```
system q{sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n//g' prixmodifAyc11.txt >prixmodifAyc12.txt};
```

or

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

system(shell_quote('sed', ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n//g').' prixmodifAyc11.txt >prixmodifAyc12.txt');
```

Answer (score -1):

> $! is the error returned by the last system call.

Since the variable expansion do take place inside double quotes, my educated guess is that `$!` expands in the last `sed` command and it is possibly breaking the `sed` expression

A simple workaround would be to escape the dollar sign and also the escape character to make it literal `\`

```
system "sed ':a;N;\$!ba;s/\\n//g' prixmodifAyc11.txt>prixmodifAyc12.txt";
```

Comment: My problem is solve , a \ was needed before "\" and "$"
Thanks you very much for all the answers/comment :)

Comment: @ikegami I saw the point there..But I am pretty sure the op grabbed the idea from this, corrected anyways and thank you for the great eyes. `:-)`

Comment: @sjsam, Actually, the OP "grabbed the idea" from a comment on the question before you even added the broken code to your answer. Either way, the comment pointing out that your answer needed to be fixed was justified.